# How do you make a web page change without reloading the page?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

What should I look into to accomplish this.

When you select an input field some text to the right shows up.

For example: https://twitter.com/signup

Anyway i need something like that works with PHP. What should I look in to?

And also How can you query the database and not have to reload the page to see result? For example i have seen on many sites registration you can check if the a username is used without the page reloading. Dont know how to explain better.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Like Arkain said, they are making the text appear with JavaScript. PHP is server-side only, meaning it can't make any changes to the page once it has loaded.

You can however, call a PHP script dynamically (to check if a username is registered) using a technique called [AJAX](http://www.google.ca/search?q=ajax&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript, look at [this](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=10) source for instance, for some beginner tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into Ajax using jQuery. I had done some things with ajax before trying jQuery but jQuery made it so easy that I found it enjoyable to keep implementing things using it.

Answer (score 0):

Learn JavaScript. You can start with [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (a pre-made javascript toolkit of functions that help you do many things without reloading the page).

Google for a jQuery Ajax tutorial.